# Convert first letter of each word entered in a textbox to captial

Tags: javascript, textfield, capitalize

I have made a form for billing, but am having trouble converting the first letter entered in a text box to capital. I've looked around a bit, but couldn't find any luck.

Basically what I'm looking for is if possible the second I enter a letter into say first name text box it auto sets capital (if user forgets to capitalize) and then the rest are in lowercase.

Comment: What kind of form which language ?

Comment: I'm assuming the language here is javascript, not java, and have made an edit to the tags that reflects that. Let me know if I'm mistaken.

Comment: post you code here...

Comment: It is javascript I'm sorry and thanks for the edit. adeneo and dprogramz I saw those, but its not what I'm quite looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a visual need only, it can be done with css:

```
input {
   text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Comment: since he need it in a textbox i believe he is going to save those in db. so visual won't be enough.

Comment: This is the only one that "Convert first letter of each word entered in a textbox to captial" so far, even if not useful for the OP's situation.

Answer (score 1):

check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zp6k/

this function should do it:

```
function capitalize(obj)
{
    obj.value = obj.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + obj.value.slice(1);
}
```

html:

```
<input type='text' id='textfield' onkeyup='capitalize(this)'>
```

Comment: Yup - saw your edit, tried your jsfiddle, and up voted when I saw it worked. Then I deleted my comment saying you hadn't linked to the right thing.

Comment: I'm trying this out in jsfiddle, but when I type in john it doesn't convert the first letter (in this case J), which is what I'm looking for if possible. Unless I'm doing this in the wrong section.

Comment: It's working. you'll type it in the texfield on bottom right corner. or better yet, try it on your own code.

Comment: It does work. I wasn't signed in thanks a bunch really helpful code

Comment: accepting my answer would help others as well ;)

Comment: This doesn't "Convert first letter of each word entered in a textbox to captial".

Comment: he wasn't asking for that.
"Basically what I'm looking for is if possible the second I enter a letter into say first name text box it auto sets capital (if user forgets to capitalize) and then the rest are in lowercase."

Comment: His title also says "Convert first letter of each word entered in a textbox to captial", so perhaps you could have clarified the OP's requirements in a comment, before posting an answer. If I had searched for such a solution and find your answer, then I have wasted my time because it would not have worked as I had expected it to. Basically, make sure the question is a good one first.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way.

Just use jQuery and a capitalize function.

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/chace/8EE3C/2/).

```
$("#firstName").keyup(function(event) {
  var tempVal = $("#firstName").val();
  $("#firstName").val(capitaliseFirstLetter(tempVal));
});
```

Comment: Can you explain to me why this was rated down? It does exactly what was asked...

Comment: Probably because you use jQuery, which is not specified or even mentioned, without demonstrating a Javascript equivalent. You also do not show the `capitalizeFirstLetter` function which is vital to the question, the jQuery isn't. And finally it doesn't "Convert first letter of each word entered in a textbox to captial"

Comment: That's funny. The original question doesn't specify javascript only. The captializeFirstLetter function is in the working example jfiddle. You got me on the last one! =) However, to my credit reading the description of the original question they are looking for the "first letter entered in a text box to capital".

Comment: "JavaScript is a dynamically-typed language commonly used for client-side scripting. Use this tag for questions regarding ECMAScript and its dialects/implementations (excluding ActionScript). Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Comment: And what if jsFiddle is down, or the example gets deleted? Then it is no longer available. And the title, "Convert first letter of each word entered in a textbox to captial" seems pretty clear to me, in Swedish, first names can be multiples, so "Sven Göran", why would you want it to be "Sven göran"?.